# How can I lock the file in WinRT from external access?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, async-await, windows-8.1

I'm opening a file in my Windows 8 app with `ReadWrite` access but the file can still be modified outside the app. For example, open a file with `ReadWrite` and while it's still open (ie. don't dispose the `IRandomAccessStream`), go to that file in Windows Explorer and delete it. You'll see that it gets deleted, but I need it blocked so that the file system says something like:

*"Cannot delete file. It's being used by another process"*.

```
using (var stream = await File.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)); // delete the file in explorer while this waits.
}
```

Anyone know how to make this happen? How do I physically lock the file?

Comment: You'd have to write a C++/CX library that uses CreateFile2() and *omits* the FILE_SHARE_DELETE option.  A bit doubtful that you'd think this is practical.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case :/